# Assembly MIPS - Create a file, specific extension

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I am coding a program in asm, I know a bit, but no expert. I am using Mars emulator. The part I do not understand is how does one create a file and make it have an specific extension like, file.vig? What I want is to create a file, give a name I want, write to it. None of this worked so far. I have the rest of the program working, but not this file creation and modification while in run time of Mars.

res points to a string

FileName points to a string like: file.vig

```
li   $v0, 13        # system call for open file
la   $a0, FileName  # output file name
li   $a1, 577       # Open for writing (flags are 0: read, 1: write)
li   $a2, 0x1ff     # was recommended for file permissions
syscall             # open a file (file descriptor returned in $v0)
move $s6, $v0       # save the file descriptor
```

# Write to file just opened

```
li   $v0, 15        # system call for write to file
move $a0, $s6       # file descriptor 
la   $a1, res       # address of buffer from which to write
li   $a2, 15        # hardcoded buffer length
syscall  
move $a0, $s6
li $v0, 16          # close
syscall
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't check the return value from your `open` syscall. It was returning -1 because you were loading `$a1` with 577 and *not* 1 [it's not quite like `libc` and is finicky about this value].

Here's your program, slightly adjusted to demo this and retry the open with the correct options [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .data
FileName:   .asciiz "file.vig"
bad_msg:    .asciiz "open syscall failed\n"
ok_msg:     .asciiz "open was okay\n"
res:        .byte   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15

    .text
    .globl  main
main:
    li      $a1,577                 # Open for writing (flags are 0: read, 1: write)
    li      $a2,0x1ff               # was recommended for file permissions

main_retry:
    li      $v0,13                  # system call for open file
    la      $a0,FileName            # output file name

    syscall                         # open a file (descriptor returned in $v0)
    move    $s6,$v0                 # save the file descriptor
    bltz    $s6,main_fail           # did open fail? fly if yes

    la      $a0,ok_msg
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    # Write to file just opened
    li      $v0,15                  # system call for write to file
    move    $a0,$s6                 # file descriptor
    la      $a1,res                 # address of buffer from which to write
    li      $a2,15                  # hardcoded buffer length
    syscall

    move    $a0,$s6
    li      $v0,16                  # close
    syscall

main_exit:
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

main_fail:
    la      $a0,bad_msg
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    li      $a1,1                   # correct write mode (O_WRONLY)
    li      $a2,0                   # file permissions are ignored by mars
    j       main_retry
```